# Trying to understand the Levy Curve (fractal)

Tags: python, fractals

I am asked to implement a recursive function that takes a nonnegative integer n as input and returns turtle instruction encoded with letters L,R and F where L means rotate left 45 degrees, R means rotate right 45 degress and F means go forward.

Additional information i have i: for every nonnegative integer n>0, the Levy curve `L(n)` can be defined in terms of Levy curve `L(n-1)`; Levy curve `L(0)` is just a straight line.

```
    usage:
    >>> lev(0)
    'F'
    >>> lev(1)
    'LFRRFL'
```

I am very new to this and I am not sure how to start:

so far I only got:

```
    from turtle import Screen, Turtle
    def lev(n):
        # base case
        if n ==0:
           return 'F'
        # recursive case
        else:
            return lev(n-1)
```

I need some good pointers here please.

Comment: when `n` is not `0` you probably want to do something besides just call `n-1`.  maybe something like `return 'L%sRR%sL' % (lev(n-1), lev(n-1))`

Comment: im sorry, what does this mean? 'L%sRR%sL' - like what is 's' and why do you mod 'L' with 's'

Comment: In addition to modulus, `%` can also be used to format the contents of a string: see [Old string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting). But [str.format](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=format#str.format) is what all the _cool_ developers use, these days :-)

Comment: Are you committed to using recursion to solve this problem? Because an iterative L system seems easier to implement. Wikipedia has done most of the work for you, by [defining the starting state and replacement rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_C_curve#L-system_construction).

Comment: lev(1) >>> 'LFRRFL'. You got this as data? Or you are assuming it?

Comment: Paulo Bu - lev(1) >>> 'LFRRFL' is data I have got, it is the result i need to get when my code is executed. Im just fumbling in the dark here. like what does the n (nonnegative integer) repressent in terms of the curve?
Kevin - yes i need to use the recursive method

Comment: if you guys can help me understand this so that i can do it in front of class I will get an A, so please help me out guys :)

Comment: Here's a hint. Many fractals, including the Levy curve, can be represented using an L system, which repeatedly takes a *string* and *replaces* some characters according to a set of rules. Python has a *string* type, which has a method allowing you to [replace](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=format#str.replace) some characters with others.

Comment: Do you need to paint the curve with turtle or just print the LFR characters for the solution?

Comment: i just need to return the encoded instructions (LFR)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since [Levy C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_C_curve)'s [L system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindenmayer_system) only has a single rule, it's simple to build the resulting string using a single [replace](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=format#str.replace) method.

```
def lev(n):
    if n == 0:
        return "F"
    else:
        symbols = lev(n-1)
        return symbols.replace("F", "LFRRFL")

for i in range(4):
    print lev(i)
```

Result:

```
F
LFRRFL
LLFRRFLRRLFRRFLL
LLLFRRFLRRLFRRFLLRRLLFRRFLRRLFRRFLLL
```

You can visualize this replacement by imagining each straight line in the figure being replaced by two smaller lines connected at a ninety degree angle. Like so:

[image]

Comment: so I am basically replacing F with LFRRFL recursivelly?

Comment: Yep, that is traditionally how the Levy C curve is constructed.

Comment: oh now I see :)

so every straight line transforms according to a fixed pattern?

Answer (score 1):

First, in case this is the problem:  A large Levy curve (recursive case) is constructed by arranging two smaller ones facing each other 'across the room', with two more 'on the floor' facing up, in between.  A small Levy curve (base case) is just a straight line.  So indeed, the base case is:

```
def lev(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 'F'
    else:
        # Recursive case here
```

But for the recursive case, you just have it call lev(n-1).  You are right that you will need to do this, but you will need to do it four times, and rotate in between.  This will create the desired 'two smaller curves facing each other, with two in between'.

Inspecting the curve carefully (here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Levy_C_construction.png), we see that we will need to draw one curve, then turn right, then draw another, then turn completely around, then draw a third curve, and finally, turn right and draw the final curve.

This can be done fairly simply:

```
dev lev(n):
    if n == 0:
        # Base case
        return 'F'
    else:
        # Recursive case
        # Calculate the smaller curve
        smaller = lev(n-1)
        # Add in the turning in between the smaller curves
        final = smaller        # First curve
        if n%2 == 0:           # Even depths require right turns
            final += 'RR'        # Rotate 90 degrees
            final += smaller     # Second curve
            final += 'RRRR'      # Rotate 180 degrees
            final += smaller     # Third curve
            final += 'RR'        # Rotate 90 degrees
            final += smaller     # Final curve
        else:                  # Odd depths require left turns
            final += 'LL'        # Rotate 90 degrees
            final += smaller     # Second curve
                                 # (No full rotation in odd depths)
            final += smaller     # Third curve
            final += 'LL'        # Rotate 90 degrees
            final += smaller     # Final curve
        return final           # Done!
```

Comment: but i will not get any left turns here.

i need to produce results like these:

        >>> lev(1)
        'LFRRFL'

Comment: @Snarre Oh oops!  I over looked something about the fractal:  some depths require right turns and some require left.  I was only looking at a single depth level.  Lemme fix that...

Comment: @Snarre Done!  Thank you for commenting on the problem instead of simply down-voting my answer and leaving it :)

Comment: no worries, im just trying to learn this...im still confused with what the the actual inputed integer repressents in the curve. Like for example if i put in 5 as n. What does that mean?

Comment: Imagine describing how to run a mile.  You might say "In order to run a mile, you need to run two half-miles"  (Recursive case).  If you just kept saying that forever, you would never actually move.  So somewhere along the line, I need to say "In order to run any less that a foot, just take one step" (Base case).  So a mile is built up out of half-miles, which are made of quarter-miles, etc, all the way down to single steps.  So what the n represents is "How many times do I need to break this down in order to reach the base case?"

Comment: I ran this for n=1 (fixing the `dev lev` typo first), and got a T shape. The level 1 Levy curve is supposed to look like a V.

Comment: Ah, it seems I overlooked another difference in odd and even iterations.  I'll just fix that up...

Answer (score 0):

My Answer

```
import turtle

def draw(n):
    l=10
    if n == 0:
        turtle.forward(l)
    else:
         turtle.left(45)
         draw(n - 1)
         turtle.right(45)
         turtle.right(45)
         draw(n-1)
         turtle.left(45)

draw(12)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64776372/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.